# Ordering table rows by time PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a following query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM phpvms_schedules ORDER BY deptime + 0 ASC";
```

In the table, I call $list variable to get database results from the above variable. I then, have a foreach statement

```
foreach($list as $flight)
```

One of the columns echoes departure time value of a flight in a HH:MM format.

```
<td>'.$flight->deptime.'</td>
```

Essentially, I want to order the times in ascending order, going up, but I'm probably missing a step, because it doesn't do it. It does it like this:

17:30
17:55
17:15
17:45
17:25

I performed a small check on the $query changing ASC to DESC, but the same thing happens, obviously with descending times.

Comment: What is the structure of your table and the data type of `deptime`?

Comment: What's the format of your `deptime` field ?

Comment: Why are you adding 0 to deptime?  Have you tried removing the zero?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how deptime is stored in the database, also the significance of the + 0.

Comment: 'deptime' is a VARCHAR(15) however I'm not sure if the CMS allows me to change it, does it normally affect anything?

Comment: if you want to mysql to order by time you should change it to TIME

Comment: Well, now I feel stupid. I haven't even noticed the +0 and now it works :| Thank you and apologies.

Comment: I suspect the `+0` was added to try to force it to an integer, which - as you say - turns out to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change `deptime` from `VARCHAR` to `TIME` (proper way)
2. Query like `ORDER BY deptime` or `ORDER BY deptime ASC`